# writing more optimized code and reusing code in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oop, design-patterns

I'm writing a desktop application using C# winforms and MSSQL server 2012. there are several classes exit in this application that need to connect to database and all uisng ADO.Net. this is on of my classes :

```
  class Prices
{
    private int id = 0;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    private string materialName = string.Empty;
    ......
    ......
    ......

     public void updateMaterialPrice()
    {                        
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secaloFormulaCS"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conString))
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateMaterialPrice", sqlCon))
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("materialName",MaterialName);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("unitPrice", Price);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("carbohydrate", Carbohydrtate);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("protein", Proterin);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fat", Fat);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("humidity", Humadity);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("minerlas", Minerlas);
                sqlCon.Open();
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlCon.Close();
                sqlCon.Dispose();
            }                                                   
    }         
    public void addMaterial()
    {
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secaloFormulaCS"].ToString(); 
        using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spAddMaterial",sqlCon))
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("materialName", MaterialName); 
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("unitPrice",Price);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("carbohydrate",Carbohydrtate);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("proterin", Proterin); 
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fat",Fat); 
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("humidity", Humadity); 
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("minerals",Minerlas);
            sqlCon.Open();
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCon.Close();
            sqlCon.Dispose(); 
        }
```

as you can see in addMterial() and updateMaterialPrice() i use the same code to connect to database and call a stored procedure and this is repeated for several times in my other classes. how can i prevent this code repetition ? is it any way to just write the code needed for connection and query the database one time and reuse it several times according to situation needed ?

Comment: Create a database_class which will handle all the database manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a Factory pattern for my Database connections, this means I never have to open a SqlConnection or pass connection strings around my program.

Here is an example for the method I use to run a query that returns multiple rows.

I would call the method from a "makeObject" method that would turn this datatable into an object.

```
public static class DB
{
    private static readonly string connectionString   = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    private static readonly DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");

    /// <summary>
    /// Use when returning data from multiple rows
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">query</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">declared parameters</param>
    /// <returns>datatable of db rows</returns>
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sql, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection  = connection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = sql;

                    if (parameters != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                        {
                            if (parameter != null)
                                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                        }
                    }
                    using (DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter())
                    {
                        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(dt);

                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ,beautiful piece of code! where did u learn to write code like this ? in university no body ever teach us like that ?

Comment: @Latrochemist I would recommend reading [Head First Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could make a helper method to prepare the command for you, or at least fill the parameters, eg.

```
void PrepareParameters(SqlCommand cmd)
{
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("materialName",MaterialName);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("unitPrice", Price);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("carbohydrate", Carbohydrtate);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("protein", Proterin);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fat", Fat);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("humidity", Humadity);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("minerlas", Minerlas);
}
```

Ideally, unless you want to use a ready ORM like Entity Framework (usually a good idea), you'd create a few abstract classes to handle these kinds of things, so that you'll save on code reuse.

For example, the `PrepareParameters` method could be abstract, and there could be an abstract property that returns the name of the SP to update, create or delete (or better yet, you could follow a naming scheme so that you'd only need one name). Then you could write 99% of the logic in the abstract base classes, and only prepare the parameters in the actual derived classes, thus cutting code repetition a *lot*.

Comment: Even with EF. I use EF but do all sp calls in my own code. EF is very easy - no dealing with parameters, you call a method of type (return class) and put in the parameters, the rest is done automatically. You can cut that down to a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

Some options are as follows:

1. Write a SqlHelper class which does the repetitive grunt work of executing a stored procedure. (especially ExecuteNonQuery ones, so that you don't need to worry about return types.)

e.g.

```
public void ExecuteQuery(string sprocName, SqlParamater[] parameters)
{
 // initialize connection
 // construct command with sprocName and parameters
 // ExecuteNonQuery
}
```

1. Use Linq2Sql

This is an excellent quick ORM tool which simplies data access to a great deal.

1. Use Entity Framework

This is an increasingly used ORM tool.

All of the above approaches have their pros/cons. You need to weight them & select the right method.